# Bootstrap Checkbox Name

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I haven't used checkboxs with the Bootstrap library yet so I'm trying to clarify something. I've been reading the documentation on Bootstrap form elements and noticed that none of the checkboxs have a `name` attribute. It has been my understanding that a checkbox needs a name.

For example this is what the Bootstrap website gives as an example:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
```

But if I were to use this wouldn't it have a `name` attribute like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="bootstrapCheck">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that they add the name, you can always add the name to it according to your requirement.

The name attribute is used to reference form data after it's submitted, and to reference the data using JavaScript on the client side

Comment: So since I'm sending data to my server side script I would need to add a name but there are circumstances where its not required. Makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted some clarification on that.